# Android Play Store: Account Switching Bug on Updates

Tags: google-play-services

I'm encountering a persistent issue on Android's Play Store related to app updates and in-app purchases (IAP) when users have multiple Google accounts on their devices. The problem arises when an app initially installed under one account switches to another after an update, causing users to lose their IAP items. The lack of a mechanism to allow users to select the preferred account for purchases adds complexity to the problem. Staged rollouts seem to exacerbate the issue, and the Play Store app on Android appears to disregard user account preferences.

Has anyone found a reliable workaround for this, or are there suggestions on how to address this issue effectively? I'm particularly interested in insights from developers who have faced similar challenges and potential solutions that could mitigate the impact on user experience. Any advice or experiences shared would be greatly appreciated.